# was it a bug with ng-repeat and ngInclude?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to load different templates like this,

```
<div ng-class="{active:$first,in:$first,'tab-pane':true}" id="{{p.path}}_settings" ng-repeat="p in panes" ng-include="buildPath(p.path)">
</div>
```

And the controller,

```
$scope.panes = [{
  name: 'xxx',
  path: 'alarm'
}, {
  name: 'yyy',
  path: 'scan'
}, {
  name: 'zzz',
  path: 'client'
}];

$scope.buildPath = function(path) {
  return 'templates/partials/settings_' + path + '.html';
}
```

It works perfectly. But now I want to disable caching, so I did this,

```
$scope.buildPath = function(path) {
  return 'templates/partials/settings_' + path + '.html?_=' + Date.now();
}
```

And the browser stuck at loading bunches of duplicated pages.

Any ideas? Was it a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than generating a new template url, you could remove the previous from the cache (in this case, the `$templateCache`).

It's as simple as injecting `$templateCache` and using the `remove` function to clear the previous URL:

```
$scope.buildPath = function(path) {
  var url = 'templates/partials/settings_' + path + '.html';
  $templateCache.remove(url);
  return url;
}
```

Alternatively, here's a directive you could also decorate your `div` with:

```
app.directive('no-cache', ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.ngInclude, function(new, old){
                $templateCache.remove(old);
            });
        }
    };
    return directive;
}]);
```